# Conversion for Hex to INT16 - Big Endian (AB) in JS

Tags: javascript

I need to convert this hex "0137" to int16 - Big Endian(AB), and I need to get this value 3.11

I written a code to get hex and everything else but this step I don't know how to do, can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I already asked a question about float conversion but I'm new to all this and I could really use some help.

Comment: `3.11` is not an int. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick hex to int converter:

```js
  let arr = "0137".split("");
  let items = arr.map((pr, index) => ({
    index: arr.length - index - 1,
    value: Number(pr)
  }));

  let result = 0;

  for(let it of items) {
    console.log(it)
    result = result + it.value * Math.pow(16, it.index);
  }

  console.log(result);
```

Comment: Even quicker one: `parseInt("0137", 16);`.

Comment: Haha, didn't know about that one!

Comment: Thanks guys, I really didn't thought of parseInt() because I used it in another project and it looked to simple to be true hahah, because when I saw INT16 - Big Endian (AB), I thought it will be harder than this, so I didn't tried it... anyway, thanks for helping me! I guess sometimes you need to keep it simple :D